# Opencv: resizing window does not work

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

```
cv2.namedWindow('output',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow('input',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("input", 50, 50)
cv2.resizeWindow("output", 50, 50)
```

The above simply does not work... No matter how I change the width and height of the cv2.resizeWindow the two windows are simply way too big to fit into the screen. Changing the window_normal to window_autosize does not work either..

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this was a very stupid mistake. I accidentally destroyed the window I created before calling cv2.imshow. I guess the lesson learnt from here is that you can call cv2.imshow without calling cv2.namedwindow first, but by default the size may be not what you want..